# User's cant upload images on published website

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I have a website which you can upload pictures and see them. I was uploading and gettin pictures with no problem on localhost but after publishing with freewebhostingarea i get these errors.

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/pexels-garvin-st-villier-3874337.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vhosts/jdm-sepeti.eu5.org/addCarF.php on line 22

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpHdU7FE' to 'img/pexels-garvin-st-villier-3874337.jpg' in /home/vhosts/jdm-sepeti.eu5.org/addCarF.php on line 22

This is how i upload images on php:

```
$target = "img/" . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$fileType = pathinfo($target, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png');
    if (in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target))...
```

I'm using the phpmyadmin that freewebhosting provides. I'would be glad if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you have write permission in the upload folder of the server

Comment: How can i check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the directory chmod permission to 0777. :)

Comment: All website files are uploaded on freewebhosting area. How do i change it

Comment: first check your web hosting for FTP credentials, using the ftp cred, you can use ftp client like FileZilla. You can follow the tutorial on the link below for your reference [Link](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ftp/change-permissions/)